# multiple user with multiple database connections at the same time

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, api, enterprise-library

**Requirement :**

Multiple user can work on different database at the same.

User-1 connected to DB-X

User-2 connected to DB-Y

-

**What I Did :**

1. I have added a parameter of dbName with Api request.
   Getting this variable in Initialize method of BaseApiController.

   ```
   var selectedDbName = Convert.ToString(this.ControllerContext.RouteData.Values["SelectedDbName"]);
   StaticClass.SelectedDbName = selectedDbName
   ```
2. In My BaseRepository when Getting database connection then by using this StaticClass.SelectedDbName i am creating a new sql connection as per following code.

   ```
   var connectionString = GetConnectionStringByDbName(StaticClass.SelectedDbName);
   _db = new SqlDatabase(connectionString);
   ```

**Problem :** 
When multiple user send request at the same time. Then conflict occur. And last connection is using for other users.

Comment: Static classes in ASP.NET are shared among all requests.  Sounds like you need to rethink your design for selecting the DB.

Comment: But its value is changing on every ajax request. Anyhow, what other solution you recommend for this requirement?

Comment: It's changing because you have multiple requests from multiple users setting the same variable to different values. The way to fix it is don't use a static class. Either use the `Session` or pass a value to the various methods that need it.

Comment: in WebAPI to DataAccessLayer, i can not use Session.

Comment: is there any alternative for HttpContext.Current.Session in Class library? Because in my database manager class library i can not use HttpContext.

Comment: Then pass the necessary value(s) to the DataAccessLayer.  Static variables are shared across all requests.  There's no easy way around that.